# On the order of the Coxeter matrix of a poset

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, matrices, posets

Let $P$ be a finite connected poset.
The Cartan matrix $C_P$ of $P$ is defined as the matrix with entries $c_{i,j}=1$ if $i \leq j$ and $c_{i,j}=0$ else for $i,j \in P$.
The Coxeter matrix of $P$ is defined as $M_P\mathrel{:=}-C_P^{-1}C_P^T$. The order of a matrix $M$ is defined as the smallest $k$ such that $M^k=\operatorname{id}$.

> Question 1: Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra (such as the incidence algebra of $P$) with an odd number of simples. Does the Coxeter matrix of $A$ have even order?

The answer is yes, following the [suggestion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377948/on-the-order-of-the-coxeter-matrix-of-a-poset#comment959027_377948) of Richard Stanley to show that the Coxeter matrix has $-1$ as an eigenvalue:

The characteristic polyomial of the Coxeter matrix is equal to (with $C$ the Cartan matrix of $A$): $\det(C^{−1})\det(C^T+xC)$ and one just needs to show $det(C^T−C)=0$ when the number of points of $P$ is odd. Since $C^T−C$ is skew-symmetric this should follow.

> Question 2: Is it true that the order of $M_P$ is bounded by $n^2$ when $n \geq 2$ is the number of points of the poset $P$?

This is true for $n \leq 7$.

Comment: Could the stronger result be true that if $P$ has an odd number of elements, then $M_P$ has an eigenvalue equal to $-1$?

Comment: @RichardStanley It is true for $n=3$ and $n=5$. Good idea.

Comment: It's usually considered bad form to completely change the question via an edit.

Comment: @SamHopkins Ok, thanks. I added the old question 2 again and answered question 1 as it was probably trivial (after the suggestion of Richard Stanley).